# How to adjust sensitivity of my touchpad?

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

I have a Dell Precision 5520 which came originally with Ubuntu 16.04. I updated to 20.04 and somewhere along the way I wound up having to tweak some settings to reduce the touchpad's sensitivity. Then I switched to Manjaro. I liked the XFCE interface, but not the random reboots, so now I've returned to Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately, I no longer recall what I did to "fix" the touchpad. Here's what what xinput tells me.

```
% xinput list | grep Touchpad
DLL07BF:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad               id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
% xinput --list-props 17
Device 'DLL07BF:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (209):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (211): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (361): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (362): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (363):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (364):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (365):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (366):   0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (367):  1, 0
libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (368):  1, 0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (343):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (344):   0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (369):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (370):    1
libinput Scroll Methods Available (345):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (346):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (347):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (371): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (372):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (373):    1, 0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (350):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (351):    0
libinput Accel Speed (352): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (353): 0.000000
libinput Left Handed Enabled (357): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (358): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (328): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (329):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (330):    0, 0
Device Node (331):  "/dev/input/event14"
Device Product ID (332):    1739, 31251
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (359):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (360):   1
```

When I ask the search engines, I wind up with "Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. DLL07BF:01 06CB:7A13 Touchpad". None of the properties look like they are related to sensitivity. What can I do to solve this hyper-sensitive touchpad?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I needed to install the Synaptics driver and restart. The output of xinput list then showed all kinds of Synaptics stuff. Using the info on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

I was able to at least change the sensitivity. Now to tweak it a bit more...

Comment: Eh, I'm still having trouble, even with the Synaptics driver installed. My laptop's touchpad actually has switches underneath. I can't seem to keep button presses from being detected with very light touches (far too light to activate the switch). I can see all those spurious button presses when running xinput --test. At this point I would be happy of all non-switch button presses were disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: I had similar problems that were driving me crazy! If you have settings for Touchpad > Taps > Corners, make sure all the options are set to "No action". That way taps and clicks (the button[s] under your touchpad) should register as normal without multiple competing events occurring... assuming you haven't already done this of course :-|